# Is it possible to iterate over a json object having `\n` and \`` characters in typescript?

Tags: json, typescript

I have a json object which is something like below:

```
"\"{\\n  \\\"Foo\\\" : \\\"1234\\\",\\n}\""
```

Is it somehow possible to iterate through this json object?I tried but my logic did not work which i feel is basically because of these `\n` and `\` i am unable to iterate.How can i get rid of these unnecessary characters ?

Comment: There is no thing as a _"JSON object"_. [JSON](https://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure (usually an object or an array but the list is not limited to them). In order to process it (other than storing or sending through the network), a JSON needs to be parsed, to recreate from it data structures similar to those used to create it. The question contains something that seems to be a JSON (i.e. a string) encoded as JSON (i.e. encoded one time more than needed). The inner JSON is, in fact, not a JSON because of the trailing comma; it is valid JavaScript code but not JSON.

Comment: @axiac - To be fair, a string like `"{\"Foo\": \"1234\"}"` is arguably a JSON object, in that it's JSON (text) that describes an object. ;-) But yeah. (And yes, below I assumed the OP just left out the further properties to keep it short...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you've shown is double-encoded JSON **if** we assume that you've removed some of the content (it has a trailing `,` in the JSON, which JSON doesn't allow).

If you run it through `JSON.parse`, you get a string containing JSON for an object.

If you run that through `JSON.parse`, you get an object.

E.g.:

```
const parsedOnce = JSON.parse(str);
const obj = JSON.parse(parsedOnce);
```

Then you loop through that object's properties in the normal way (`for-in`, `Object.keys`, `Object.entries`, etc.).

Live Example:

```js
const str = "\"{\\n  \\\"Foo\\\" : \\\"1234\\\"\\n}\"";
const parsedOnce = JSON.parse(str);
const obj = JSON.parse(parsedOnce);
for (const key in obj) {
    console.log(`${key} = ${obj[key]}`);
}
```

That code is also valid TypeScript ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBNBOMC8MBEAdVBvd6wxl0wDEQQjUYAuQ3VARgCYBmAFgtzAF9NUBuAFChIsAA4BDeBACmAEwDyYYNOQwAUgGV5AOQB0EqdIAUCAJSDh0GCABGAK1Wad+yTKMGZCpdPMCAZiCIRpawANbSAJ4wAJb4tnamMFgCBASWIAA20roZIADmRgAGACRY4RFcqqXxANrlALpchb5cQA)), though if you have a type you can apply to `obj` so it doesn't default to `any`, that would be good. (You could apply `{[key: string]: any}` to it at minimum.)

Comment: I parsed it just once and that is why was unable to iterate through the object!thanx a lot!

Comment: @Sakshi - You're welcome! Once really should be all you need, whatever is producing that should only stringify it once rather than twice... :-)